Multiple VLANs, one network. Or: Multiple VLANs, same network
I'm a provider. I'm out of IP4s. There are no more IP4 allocations available.
However, I'm using 4 IPs per 1 customer because the fiber network switches are using VLANs to route to customers.
How do I, for example, give 127 different VLANs each a unique IP out of a /25, such that each is routed there?
Let's say my IP is 3.8.3.1/25.  How do I allocate 3.8.3.2 to vlan 3001, 3.8.3.3 to vlan 3002, ... 3.8.3.127 to vlan 3127?

Requirement 1:  These IPs have to be able to communicate with eachother.
Requirement 2:  DHCP
Requirement 3:  Should be compatible with traffic shaping.


There's no causal pathway from "the modems are using VLANs" to "I'm using 4 public IP addresses per customer", that just doesn't make sense. VLANs are an Ethernet-layer thing, IP addresses are at least one layer above. So, why exactly do you need 4 addresses per customer? (I'm a bit worried because you say that you're a provider… you don't seem to be very clear about your networking stack.)

It's also not quite certain whether you are now talking about routing things on a Linux computer, or switching them on the fiber network switches? Or is this some other kind of setup? A detailled schematic diagram that shows which devices are involved here and what exactly they are supposed to do would definitely help!

Among all the architecture, you should, regarding your requirements clarify: 1. Which part of your infrastructure is going to do the DHCP? What exactly is the information you plan to disseminate via DHCP, and to which device(s)? 3. Traffic shaping: that can mean everything and nothing. Please describe the kind of traffic shaping you have in mind, and which part of the system needs to shape which part of the traffic, according to which criteria? Is the part that observes these criteria the same machine as the one doing the shaping, or a different one?

Which problem exactly are you trying to solve with VLANs? Is that not in conflict with "these IPs have to be able to communicate with each other?" in the first place? And if it's not in conflict, what parts of traffic do you want them to be able to exchange, and which not?

It's all got a pretty simple answer: It's out of my control. So I have this linux router, and these VLANs point to these customers (done over some third party's switch network I have no knowledge of the details), and have to give internet access (which should include eachother), with very limited IP space.
The note about shaping: this is just tc queues to limit bandwidth, which just means 'I'd like to have an in-kernel solution, not a separate ppp program I'd have to shoehorn the ability to limit speeds into somehow'.


I'm using 4 IPs per 1 customer because the fiber network switches are using VLANs to route to customers

I'm assuming that means you're using a /30 per VLAN at the moment. The intermediate improvement would be to use a /31 (with two host addresses and zero reserved addresses) – not all systems support it yet as it's a relatively recently standardized special case, but many already do; and while it's not as dense as you're asking, it is nevertheless 2x as efficient as the traditional /30, as well as being simpler to implement than the request.
192.168.5.4/30
  192.168.5.4 - legacy broadcast
  192.168.5.5 - host A
  192.168.5.6 - host B
  192.168.5.7 - standard broadcast

192.168.5.4/31
  192.168.5.4 - host A
  192.168.5.5 - host B
  no reserved addresses

Going further from there would be to use a pair of /32's – that is, no "subnet" at all, but an explicit route to the peer address. Linux supports this, commonly known as "pointopoint" configuration, as do most BSDs, and very often it is used with the same local address on multiple interfaces – that doesn't cause problems because a /32 doesn't expand to any overlapping subnet routes. This would be one of the two methods for implementing what you're asking for – assuming all involved systems support it.
eth0.3 - ip addr add 192.168.5.1/32 peer 192.168.5.3/32
eth0.4 - ip addr add 192.168.5.1/32 peer 192.168.5.4/32
eth0.5 - ip addr add 192.168.5.1/32 peer 192.168.5.5/32
...

Which is really short for "address 192.168.5.1/32, and also route 192.168.5.3/32 over this interface", in the same way as subnet masks are short form of a device route.
The problem with this is that I'm not sure if it's possible to deploy the opposite configuration via DHCP. (Although it would be fairly common for PPP links, such as PPPoE.)
In order to use DHCP, you'd need to add Proxy-ARP so that your customer devices think they're on a /25, even though it's not configured as a /25 on your side. That is, they can receive a standard DHCP lease indicating a /25 netmask and they can successfully ARP for another customer's IP address (getting your gateway's MAC instead) – while on your side you still have only a /32 on each VLAN interface, as in the previous example.
Linux has built-in Proxy-ARP as an interface setting (for "global" proxying) or as special neighbor cache entries (for more precise proxying), but userspace implementations also exist; e.g. I use parpd to proxy a /26 into another VLAN for historical reasons.
This should be mostly compatible with DHCP servers, although there won't be any automatic association between leases and routes – you'll probably need to manually ensure that the VLAN with Customer A has the correct /32 routed through it (either as a 'peer' parameter or as a normal static route, doesn't matter).

Nice answer! Would be interesting how OP matches that to their network! Also worth noting that a paying customer will most definitely also want IPv6 connectivity (it's 2024, not 2004), so that raises the next question on how to manage this on a dual stack, or whether it migth make more sense to do all this only for IPv6 only, and to circumvent the "2 IPv4 addresses minimal subnet" routing problem with either DS Lite (with or without NAT?) or with IPv6-mapped IPv4 addresses directly.

Unfortunately I know next to nothing about how real commercial ISPs operate (our NREN just statically routes everything towards us). Yes, you can circumvent the "2 addresses" limit by directly routing e.g. an IPv4 /32 via the CPE's IPv6 address, but you can already circumvent that using regular /32 routes as in the post's example – and it would have the same problem of deploying such a configuration via DHCP, only even more so; whereas DS-Lite (which I know nothing about) is probably at least standard enough that it would be understood by many random CPE routers.

Hmm yesterday when I use peer (configured through networkd) on a pair of veths (connecting an nspawn and the host) it seems to suppress ARP. I have been wondering if it's a bug, or I have missed something, or if it wasn't supposed to be used on a link that requires ARP resolution. (Literally just commenting the Peer= lines and adding back /30 to Address= lines under [Address] get me back communication.)

@grawity Real ISPs tend to use commercial proprietary platforms like juniper or microtik routers, which have PPPoE built in as a 1st class option, all managed for them. Of course, these cost $$$ compared to linux. (And lock you into proprietary vendor lock-in software). Linux'PPP support is much more rudimentary, very difficult to configure, and little guidance can be found online. While these products are almost plug and play web interfaces.

Just found out the culprit of peer not working for me: I have arp_ignore=1. And it seems to be a somewhat "awkward" situation that has persisted for quite some time: https://serverfault.com/a/936885

Yeah, I was going to guess that it was one of the arp_ knobs – although arp_ignore=1 should still work properly; it's arp_ignore=2 that is more likely to break.
